# Skipping over the first line of a text file using readlines() in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, txt

I'm a beginner programmer trying to build a password manager in python. I've been trying to write a function that allows you to view the contents of the text file by printing them to the console.
`

```
def view():
    with open("passwords.txt", "r") as p:
        for line in p.readlines():
            if line == p.readlines()[0]:
                pass
            data = line.rstrip()
            user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("User: ", user, "| password: ", passw)
```

for context, the very first line of my text file is a heading so I want to skip over the first line. I thought that the `readlines()` method returns a list of all strings in the text file, however, when I try accessing the first line through indexing I get an

```
'IndexError: list index out of range' error.
```

What is the correct approach of skipping the first line, or any line for that matter of a text file?
thank you this is my first time posting on here

Comment: How about putting `next(p)` or `p.readline()` before the `for` loop? It will read a line, and then just throw it away.

Comment: You can do `p.readline()` before entering the loop.  `readlines()` DOES return all the lines in the file, but when it finishes, the file is positioned at end-of-file.  There's nothing else to read.  It doesn't rewind and start over.

Comment: Looks like your files are pipe-delimited? Why not use `.csv` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p.readline()` or `next(readline)` to skip a line, before you loop over the remaining lines. This will read a line, and then just throw it away.

`foo.txt`:

```
this is the end
hold your breath
and count to ten
```

Code:

```
with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')

# hold your breath
# and count to ten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use readlines()[n:] to skip the first n line(s).

```
with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as p:
    lines = p.readlines()[1:]  # skipping first line
    for line in lines:
        data = line.rstrip()
        user, passw = data.split("|")
        print("User: ", user, "| password: ", passw)
```